# Woocommerce Breadcrumb separator missing

Tags: php, html, woocommerce

I tried to remove the base shop tag from my breadcrumbs so that it should look like this:

**Home / Category / Subcategory / Productname**

instead of:

**Home / Shop / Category / Subcategory / Productname**

I found this solution on stackoverflow which helped a lot and removed the "shop" from the breadcrumbs

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'remove_shop_crumb', 20, 2 );
function remove_shop_crumb( $crumbs, $breadcrumb ){
    foreach( $crumbs as $key => $crumb ){
        if( $crumb[0] === __('Shop', 'Woocommerce') ) {
            unset($crumbs[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $crumbs;
}
```

Problem is that it now looks like that

**Home / Category / SubcategoryProductname/**.

Subcategory and Productname aren't separate by an / anymore and the / is at the end of the productname. Why is that? What is missing their to get the / between subcategory and productname?

Comment: You will need to append the forward slash after you have removed the crumbs.

Comment: And where should i do this?

Comment: Im checking now but it might depend on the theme you are using.

Comment: The easiest way to remove "Shop" would be to change your permalink settings to the defaults http://yourdomain.com/product/sample-product/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the separator back in by using array_push. Note: you may need to change the forward slash "  /  " to match your separator.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'remove_shop_crumb', 20, 2 );
function remove_shop_crumb( $crumbs, $breadcrumb ){
    foreach( $crumbs as $key => $crumb ){
        if( $crumb[0] === __('Shop', 'Woocommerce') ) {
            unset($crumbs[0]);
            array_push($crumbs," / ");
       }
    }

    return $crumbs;
}
```